# Where to put await in async function

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise

I am trying to use an async call however whenever I put the await command word in, the script fails to run.
Any suggestions gratefully accepted.

alternative code at bottom based on comment provided

```js
    async function masterDeploy(PrimaryControl){
        //2. Collect learning event dates from programme
        LearnEvents = progLearnerEvent(progGuid)                                                                                
          .then(LearnEvents =>{
            console.log(LearnEvents)                                                                    
            for (var b = 0; b < LearnEvents.length; b++) {                                          
              retLearnEvents(LearnEvents[b],progGuid,b) //need to wait for these results before moving to next loop, code does not run if await placed at beginning of this line
              console.log(FlightPlanArray)  
              learnEventsArrComb.push(FlightPlanArray)
              console.log(learnEventsArrComb)
            }
            return learnEventsArrComb
          })
          .then(learnEventsArrComb => {
            console.log(learnEventsArrComb)
          })
          .catch(error =>
              {DisplayError(error)}
            );
```

alternative starts here

```js
        LearnEvents = progLearnerEvent(progGuid)    
            await (LearnEvents =>{
            //.then(LearnEvents =>{
              console.log(LearnEvents)                                                                  
              for (var b = 0; b < LearnEvents.length; b++) {                                            
                await retLearnEvents(LearnEvents[b],progGuid,b) //need to wait for these results before moving to next loop, code does not run if placed at beginning of this line
                console.log(FlightPlanArray)    
                learnEventsArrComb.push(FlightPlanArray)
                console.log(learnEventsArrComb)
              }
              return learnEventsArrComb
            })
            //.then(learnEventsArrComb => {
            //  console.log(learnEventsArrComb)
            //})
            //.catch(error =>
            //      {DisplayError(error)}
            //);
      
      }
```

Comment: Start by replacing the `.then()` calls with `await` syntax. *Then* you can add the `await` in the loop.

Comment: Do you mean rewrite the progLearnerEvent promise as an async as well?

Comment: `progLearnerEvent(progGuid)` already does return a promise, you don't need to rewrite the `progLearnerEvent` function. You just should use that promise with `await` instead of `.then()`.

Comment: is this what you mean?

Comment: Not really. You need to `await` the promise, and not use a callback at all.

Answer (score 0):

you  can do it like this:

```
const masterDeploy = async (PrimaryControl) =>{
        //2. Collect learning event dates from programme
        LearnEvents = await progLearnerEvent(progGuid)                                                                                
          .then(LearnEvents =>{
            console.log(LearnEvents)                                                                    
            for (var b = 0; b < LearnEvents.length; b++) {                                          
             await retLearnEvents(LearnEvents[b],progGuid,b) //need to wait for these results before moving to next loop, code does not run if await placed at beginning of this line
              console.log(FlightPlanArray)  
              learnEventsArrComb.push(FlightPlanArray)
              console.log(learnEventsArrComb)
            }
            return learnEventsArrComb
          })
          .then(learnEventsArrComb => {
            console.log(learnEventsArrComb)
          })
          .catch(error =>
              {DisplayError(error)}
            );
```

try this instead...

Answer (score -1):

You need to add `await` when you call to `masterDeploy` func

```
function main(){ 
  await masterDeploy(info)
}
```

also, I recommend to do these changes in your code:

```
async function masterDeploy(PrimaryControl){
//2. Collect learning event dates from programme
try{
    const LearnEvents = await progLearnerEvent(progGuid)  
    console.log(LearnEvents)                                                                              
    for (let b = 0; b < LearnEvents.length; b++) {                                                    retLearnEvents(LearnEvents[b],progGuid,b) //need to wait for these results before moving to next loop, code does not run if await placed at beginning of this line
        console.log(FlightPlanArray)  
        learnEventsArrComb.push(FlightPlanArray)
        console.log(learnEventsArrComb)
    }
}
catch(error){
    DisplayError(error)
}
}
```

Comment: thank you, although this code does not run either and it has the retLearnEvents call missing

Comment: "*you need to add await when you call to "masterDeploy" func*" - no.

Comment: masterDeploy is called from a button on a Microsoft Dynamics ribbon. PrimaryControl is the context that is passed so that parameters from the record can be accessed. I left this code out for brevity.
I am seeing a friend on Monday who will explain what your comment means @Bergi